# my app crashes when i use this code (using com.google.android.material 1.6.1

Tags: android, crash, android-studio-2.2

<LinearLayout

```
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
```

// getting error in this part app crashed

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
```

// using material theme version 1.6.1
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

```
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="Username"
      android:textColorHint="#757575"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash. FWIW, I cover Logcat and stack traces in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.